# WCF: How to have contract and implementation in a separate project to the .SVC file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, rest

I am trying to create a RESTful service using WCF in my ASP.NET (C#) application.

In one of my class library projects named ABC.WebApp, I have created a file for my contract and one file which implements the interface. Both files have the .cs extension.

Then, in my main web application named ABCWeb (where all the .aspx and .aspx.cs files are located), I added a new WCF Service named SPPService.svc. This automatically created a new folder at the root of ABCWeb called App_Code with two files inside. I deleted them both and the App_Code folder. I then modified the markup of the .SVC file to the following:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service = "ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.SPP.Rest.SPPService" Language="C#" %>
```

Lastly, I modified the Web.Config file to add the following section:

```
<service name="ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.SPP.REST.SPPService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehaviour">
    <endpoint name="webHttpsBinding" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.SPP.REST.ISPPService"
       behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint name="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">
    </endpoint>
</service>
```

The issue is that when I try to browse to the following link, I get an exception:

http://localhost:81/ExternalServices/WS/SPP/REST/SPPService.svc

Message: The service '/ExternalServices/WS/SPP/REST/SPPService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.SPP.Rest.SPPService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

Comment: Did you include a reference to `ABC.WebApp` in your `ABCWeb` project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service = "ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.SPP.Rest.SPPService" Language="C#" %>
```

The Service is case-sensitive ("Rest"). The corrected version is below. It's working now:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service = "ABC.WebApp.ExternalServices.WS.SPP.REST.SPPService" Language="C#" %>
```